# Find the Fourier transform of $\frac1{1+t^2}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find the Fourier transform of $$f(t)=\frac1{1+t^2}$$ using contour integration that
$$F\{f(t)\}=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac1{1+t^2}e^{2\pi ft}dt$$
How can I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the exponent be $2\pi ift$ instead of $2\pi ft$?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, it should be $2\pi ift$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I don't think you should have a function of $t$ given by $f(t)$ and then to use $f$ as your transformation variable. That is just going to cause problems.

Anyway, let

$$ g(t) = e^{-a\lvert t \rvert} $$

(you will see why we pick this function soon).

Then

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F} (g(t)) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a \lvert t \rvert} e^{-2\pi ift} dt \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{at} e^{-2\pi ift} dt  +  \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} e^{-2\pi ift} dt \\
& = \frac{e^{t(a-2\pi if)}}{a-2\pi if} \Bigg \rvert_{-\infty}^{0} + \frac{e^{-t(a+2\pi if)}}{-(a+2\pi if)} \Bigg \rvert_{0}^{\infty} \\
& = \frac{2a}{a^{2}+4\pi^{2}f^{2}} 
\end{align}$$

Using the inversion theorem

$$ \implies e^{-a\lvert t \rvert} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2a}{a^{2}+4\pi^{2}f^{2}} e^{2\pi ift} df $$

Setting $a = 2 \pi$ puts the denominator of the integrand in the form we want

$$ \implies \pi e^{-2\pi \lvert t \rvert} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+f^{2}} e^{2\pi ift} df $$

Let $t \mapsto -t$

$$\begin{align}
\implies \pi e^{-2\pi \lvert -t \rvert} & = \pi e^{-2\pi \lvert t \rvert} \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+f^{2}} e^{-2\pi ift} df
\end{align} $$

Therefore

$$ \mathscr{F}\Bigg(\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\Bigg) = \pi e^{-2\pi \lvert f \rvert} $$