# fourier transform calculate

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

$\phi(x)=\int_{\infty}^\infty (\frac{N}{k^2+\alpha^2})e^{ixk} dk$

I think this integral is related to the Fourier series. There are many obstacles in the calculation process.

This calculation is like what is in physics.
help me please.

Comment: The lower bound should be $-\infty$, I think!

Comment: I've computed this integral [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137476/finding-fourier-transform-of-inverse-polynomial/2138329#2138329) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047977/find-the-fourier-transform-of-frac11t2/1048141#1048141).

Answer (score 1):

Well, when we use Euler's formula:

$$e^{x\text{k}i}=\cos\left(x\text{k}\right)+\sin\left(x\text{k}\right)i\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(x\right):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{\text{N}}{\alpha^2+\text{k}^2}\right)\cdot e^{x\text{k}i}\space\text{d}\text{k}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\text{N}\cdot\cos\left(x\text{k}\right)+\text{N}\cdot\sin\left(x\text{k}\right)i}{\alpha^2+\text{k}^2}\space\text{d}\text{k}\tag2$$

Now, we can seperate the real and imaginary part:

- Real part:
  $$\Re\left(\mathscr{I}\left(x\right)\right)=\text{N}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos\left(x\text{k}\right)}{\alpha^2+\text{k}^2}\space\text{d}\text{k}\tag3$$
- Imaginary part:
  $$\Im\left(\mathscr{I}\left(x\right)\right)=\text{N}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(x\text{k}\right)}{\alpha^2+\text{k}^2}\space\text{d}\text{k}\tag4$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ye, I do and I know it is zero. But that is for the OP to prove :)

Comment: So, I deleted my stupid comment and just upvoted your answer. What is very interesting is the result for the real part. It is just beautiful.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Haha, it is okay! Yes, I totally agree with your statement.

Comment: it is done?? ㅠㅠ I don't understand. why it is done?