# How do you compute the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{a+j2\pi f}$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

It is well known that the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F(f(t))} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-j2\pi f t} dt$ of

$$e^{-at}, t \geq 0$$ ($a$ is a constant) is given by

$$\dfrac{1}{a+j2\pi f}$$

What is the technique one would use to perform the inverse transform?

I have tried:
$\begin{align}
\mathcal{F^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{a+j2\pi f})} & = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{a+j2\pi f} e^{j2\pi f t} df\\ & = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{a+j2\pi f}{a^2+(2\pi f)^2} e^{j2\pi f t} df  \end{align}$

However, even though this breaks into real and imaginary parts, it has significantly increased the difficulty of computing the inverse fourier transform.

Comment: 1) You can use/prove the Fourier inversion theorem. 2) In complex analysis there is the residue theorem $\text{Res}(\frac{e^{2i \pi ft}}{2i \pi (f+\frac{a}{2i\pi})},\frac{-a}{2i\pi}) = \frac{e^{-at}}{2i\pi} $. 3) Differentiating under the integral gives a way to find the answer in term of a differential equation

Comment: I did this problem using inversion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047977/find-the-fourier-transform-of-frac11t2/1048141#1048141) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137476/finding-fourier-transform-of-inverse-polynomial/2138329#2138329).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with complex analysis, one way is to perform contour integration. Consider the complex function:

$$ F(z) = \frac{e^{2\pi itz}}{a + 2\pi iz} $$

which has a simple pole at $z = \frac{a}{2\pi}i$. We define a closed contour $C$ consisting of a line from $z=-R$ to $z=R$ on the real line and an upper semicircle enclosing the pole. It looks something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_2_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution).

Then we have
$$ \int_C F(z)\ dz = \int_{-R}^{R} F(x)\ dx + \int_{C_R} F(z)\ dz $$

where $C_R$ denotes the circular arc. Using [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma), we can prove

$$ \lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{C_R} F(z)\ dz = 0 $$

Then using [the residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), we can compute the closed loop integral

$$ \begin{align} 
\int_C F(z)\ dz &= 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}\left(F(z),\frac{ai}{2\pi}\right) \\
&= 2\pi i\lim_{z\to \frac{ai}{2\pi}} \left(z- \frac{ai}{2\pi}\right) F(z) \\
&= \lim_{z\to \frac{ai}{2\pi}} e^{2\pi itz} \\
&= e^{-at} 
\end{align}
$$

Thus

$$ \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} F(z) \ dz = \int_C F(z) \ dz = e^{-at} $$